# Petersen Graph - no $3$ node circles

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

In a script about graph theory is written that the graph has girth $5$ which is pretty easy to see. Anyway the proof is the following:

- no $1$ or $2$ circles
- $3$ circles: it has to exist $3$ in pairs disjoint sets of $2$ elements (do not exist)
- $4$ circles: can be shown by showing that the neighborhood of any pair of two non adjacent nodes has exactly one common neighbor
- $5$ cirlces: easy to see

My problem are the 3 circles, I don't know how to prove the argument. It is turning in my head and I can't solve it...

Comment: Pick a vertex. Show by exhaustive search that there is no 3-cycle that includes that vertex. Argue by symmetry that there are no 3-cycles at all.

Comment: Thank you, but I still stuck with the argument from the script. Why do have to exist 3 in pairs disjoint sets of 2 elements to have atleast one 3-cycle? There isn't written if it is about node sets, but I think so. Also there is not written in which relation these nodes have to be - so the solution for this argument has to be this obvious that nearly everbody has to be able to detect it :/. Anyway thank you again for your alternative argument.

Comment: I gave the alternative argument because I couldn't make heads nor tails out of "it has to exist 3 in pairs disjoint sets of 2 elements".

Comment: Okay then we are two. I found this script this morning and thought why not learn something about graph theory. Anyway, I stopped after this argument and stuck since then :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice trick here: the Petersen graph is a [Kneser graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KneserGraph.html), precisely $\text{KG}(5,2)$, so the vertices can be seen as the $2$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, connected through an edge iff they represent disjoint subsets. If there was a $3$-cycle in the Petersen graph, there would be $3$ mutually disjoint $2$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, but that is clearly impossible since $5<6$.

In general, $\text{KG}(n,k)$ is triangle-free iff $n<3k$. Given Lovasz' theorem on the chromatic number of Kneser's graphs, $\chi(\text{KG}(n,k))=n-2k+2$, we have that there are triangle-free graphs with an arbitrarily large chromatic number. This fact is usually proved through Mycielski's construction, but there are many other [interesting approaches](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1933708/44121).

Comment: I have to say, I needed the image from wikipedia to understand the way it is constructed, yesterday, I was a little bit confused by the Kneser graph construction approach - of course now your and all the other descriptions are totally clear. Thank you very much now I am happy and can go on reading the script, you rescued my weekend :)