# Graph not $k$-colorable, without $k$-cliques

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a simple example of a graph without $k$-cliques that is not $k$-colorable. $k=3$ would be great but perhaps a larger $k$ is required for this to be possible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Check the book "Examples and Counterexamples in Graph Theory" of Capobianco and Molluzo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Construction of a triangle-free graph of chromatic number $1526$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579892/construction-of-a-triangle-free-graph-of-chromatic-number-1526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Grotzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) is the smallest example of a triangle-free graph with chromatic number $4$. It is the [Mycelskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian) of $C_5$. By considering the Mycelskian of the Grotzsch graph you have a triangle-free graph with $23$ vertices and chromatic number $5$. This procedure can be iterated.

I would point out [some fancy ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1933708/44121) for proving that there are triangle-free graphs with arbitrary chromatic number: for instance the existence of an infinite triangle-free difference graph with chromatic number $+\infty$, namely the graph whose vertices are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ and whose arcs join integers which differ by a cube.